# Making a navbar go to the correct section

Tags: html, css, xcode, navbar

I am beginner at code. I am trying to get my navbar to go to the correct sections of my HTML page. For instance, I want my skills href to go to the skills section of the html. I know I am missing something, but I do not know what it is.I greatly appreciate your help!

Here is my code for my navbar

```
<div class="Navbar" style="position: inherit;">
        <a class="active" href="#aboutme">About Me</a>
        <a class="active" href="#skills">Skills</a>
        <a class="active" href="#contactme">Contact Me</a>
</div>
```

here is my code for the #skills section. All of the sections have the same coding.

```
<div class="skills">
        <h2 class="header">Skills</h2>
            <div class="skills-img">
            <img src="HTML.png" alt="html" width="100px">
            <img src="Css.png" alt="css" width="75px">
          <img src="JavaScript-Logo.png" alt="Javascrip" width="180px">
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct section"?

Comment: Basically I was my Skills Href on the navbar to go to the skills section of my html

Comment: If I understand you correctly it should work if you change `class="skills"` to `id="skills"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the id Attribute.

Example:

```
<div id="skills">
    <h2 class="header">Skills</h2>
    <div class="skills-img">
        <img src="HTML.png" alt="html" width="100px">
        <img src="Css.png" alt="css" width="75px">
        <img src="JavaScript-Logo.png" alt="Javascrip" width="180px">
    </div>
</div>
```

I think this will help you: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html

Comment: Thank you! that worked!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#skills,#contactme,#aboutme{
margin-top:100vh;
}

#skills a, #contactme a, #aboutme a{
text-decoration:none;
}
  
a{
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
text-align:center;}

.Navbar{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;

}
```

```html
<div id='Navbar' class="Navbar" >
        <a class="active" href="#aboutme">About Me</a>
        <a class="active" href="#skills">Skills</a>
        <a class="active" href="#contactme">Contact Me</a>
</div> 


<div id='skills' class="skills">
        <h2 class="header"><a href='#Navbar'>Skills</a></h2>
            <div class="skills-img">
            
            </div>
</div>

<div id='aboutme' class="skills">
        <h2 class="header"><a href='#Navbar'>About Me</a></h2>
            <div class="skills-img">
            
            </div>
</div>


<div id='contactme' class="skills">
        <h2 class="header"><a href='#Navbar'>Contact Me</a></h2>
            <div class="skills-img">
            
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider explain why this answer works. For a begginer, a short sentence may help understand the code and where it is wrong.

Comment: I'll explain- this is working because the ```href``` knows where to go when clicked which is ```#skills``` . Initially you were putting class skills as ```#skills```.  So the ```href``` didn't know where to go because ```#skills``` didn't exist

Comment: @DCR You should always explain your answers, and not just give the code

Answer (score 0):

another option is to add an `a` tag with name attribute set it to a unique name in the webpage that you want the link to jump too, this is called fragment identifier (see Chapter 7 from: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1866), as a beginner, I advice to start studying the standards, not only online tutorials...